# when i set with condition status then in case comments should update with some information posted pic see?

Tags: trigger

[image]
See this image i got error api name of internal comments is comments but it shows as invalid sobject

Comment: There is no field comments on case. Are you sure this is not a custom field? If so it should be comments__c. Or do you mean Description?

Answer (score 1):

These problems are quite easy to resolve.  The error message states that 'comments' is not a valid field for SObject Case.

By looking at the [SFDC Objects documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/index.htm) you can see that there is no field entitled Comments in the Case object and hence you can't set it directly in Apex

So -- either set one of the out-of-box fields in Case or create a custom field on case that you can default with the "hi, this is a great day" text. Custom fields always have `__c` as the last part of their field name.

n.b. Cases have a child object called `CaseComment` - - but you won't be able to insert those child objects on a before insert trigger (you'd need an after insert trigger)